# Generate stored procedure declarations from dbml file

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, data-migration, dbml

I have a .net project with Linq to SQL used in data access layer.

The project is in development and all the stored procedures in db are added in dbml file.

Unfortunately I lost database today, so in attempt to recreate database I managed to create database schema

Now I want at-least the stored procedures to be created. I am fully aware that the logic/ code in SP can not be recovered, but at-least it has information about stored procedure name and parameter.

So is there any tool that can read my dbml file and created empty stored procedure in db with same name and parameters?

Comment: Try to parse your `DBML` as `XML` variable, and generate `DDL` statements with dynamic `SQL`.

Comment: So I need to write parser for that. Ok sounds good. Any other quicker way available? readymade parsers maybe?

Comment: OK Thanks for the help I wrote some C# code to fetch function names and params and created script out of it.

Comment: I am glad to a bit help you :)